# Way to use FakeGPS with FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient, mock-location

I working on taxi application and i need testing location updates. FakeGPS (or same small apps) provide it.

I implemented GpsTracker and its working as well, but mock location dont call locationcallback.

`client.setMockMode(true)` dont helps me.

Can you help me?